# How to build crashpad into chromium?

Tags: build, chromium, crash-reports

I built chromium for Windows 10, but crashpad didn't seem to build in it, because running `chrome --enable-crashpad` doesn't create the crashpad_handler process. On the other hand I have separately built crashpad, but it is not clear how to synchronize it with Chromium. Could you please tell me how to build crashpad directly inside chromium, preferably without re-building chromium!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to build crashpad for Chromium, it's built when compiling Chromium and runs with Chromium. But crash reporting will be disabled for Chromium builds which you can check if you goto: `chrome://crashes/` URL. You can check if crashpad is running or not by crashing the current renderer process. Open a new tab and crash the current renderer process by typing the following URL:

```
chrome://crash/
```

You should see `Aww snap` message. So that basically means, crashpad is running.

Comment: I need crash_handler, but I can't find it inside chrome/src/out/Debug, `chrome://crash/` - takes a long time to load and then chrome doesn't respond (off).
If it should be rebuilt more correct, where should the crash_handler be located?

Comment: Looks like you have built debug version of Chromium. It should load that page. Like I said, building Chromium will build crashpad and integrate it with Chromium too. Recent versions of Chromium doesn't execute that crashpad_handler process as you have mentioned in your query. Try what I said then let us know what happens

Comment: Yes, you're right, it loads the message Aw, Snap, Thanks! Although there were some crashes, but I still do not understand some points, where is the crash base to check that it really catches them! It has to log them somewhere or save them.

Comment: If you use Windows then those crash reports should be located inside (not the exact path) `program files\Google\crash reports` or `program files (x86)\Google\crash reports`. I am on Mac right now, so that's not the exact path but the path that I remember

Comment: This folder is empty, there is also no such folder in the out/Debug of my chromium. Maybe it should be compiled like target?

Comment: I built crashpad_handler, but I'm not sure if it runs with chromium, as it is not in the worker processes, can you tell me how it can run with chromium?

Comment: Chromium will start crashpad internally when launching Chromium. If I remember correctly, crash dumps might not be generated for debug versions. So you should build release versions. Try debugging Chromium from the main entry point then you will know. Also Chromium use multi-process architecture

Comment: I'm building a release to check, but what if I set the path to hendler in [that](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/third_party/crashpad/crashpad/client/crashpad_client.h#L118) function with my server url for minidumps right in the code at crashpad_client.h? Would it work and do I understand correctly that for each start of chrome, a different crashpad_handler would be created in this case, not as in the [documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad/+/HEAD/doc/overview_design.md) one for all running clients?

Comment: Multi-process architecture doesn't necessarily mean there will be multiple crash handlers for all the processes, it uses multi-process architecture for renderers, to be more specific. Also you crash dump won't be sent to your server as crash reporting will be disabled for Chromium builds. You will have to modify Chromium to enable and send crash reports to your server

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I'm trying to find a flag or a way to switch the crash reporter state to enabled [here](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/main/components/crash/core/app), but I can't find it, can you tell me where to look?

Comment: You have to modify Chromium’s source code to do so. I would recommend debugging it. I did that long time back, if I can find a reference to it then I will but not sure if I can find it

Comment: I'm trying to build now by setting the flags to true [here](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/components/crash/core/app/crash_reporter_client.h#L138), since the description says this should enable a crash report, am I right? Or is it done in a much more complicated way? If you remember

Comment: You will have to make lots of changes, so better start debugging